# Using CozyRoc control to encrypt file not working

Tags: pgp, ssis-2008

I am trying to encrypt a file to send to another company. That company has given me their public key in a pdf document. I copied it into a txt file and name it key.asc. Now I am trying to use cozyroc control to encrypt the file, but it fails every time because there is not email address associated in the OpenPGP Task Editor. In the configuration setting of the OpenPGP Task Editor, I have the PublicKeyRing pointed to the connectionstring that points to the .asc file (the public key for the receiver). But the Key dropdown has no value. Even when I try to open the dropdown, it does not show any options like email addresses or identifiers to choose from.

What am I doing wrong? Or how should I use the public key?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Anytime you want to use a public key you need to import it into a keyring. I went to gnupg.org and downloaded their free version. Once I did that I was able to import my text file using the command line utility. The documentation on gnupg.org helped. The resulting file looks the same as before, but it now shows the associated email address and works with the CozyRoc control.